# Can't inspect default.sql file from the Android Studio profiler

Tags: android, android-profiler

With my limited experiences with the Android Studio profiler, I see there is a way of exporting the CPU data but don't see any way of exporting the energy profiling data. Furthermore, when I try to read the source code of Android Studio, I see that the energy information is stored in a file called default.sql. However, I am not able to open this file correctly to get the information. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android Studio doesn't officially support exporting the energy profiling data. You are right the data is saved in a SQL file, but the schema isn't officially documented or supported. That said, you may be able to figure out the schema from the code.

Just a context, Android Studio's energy data is [mathematically calculated](https://cs.android.com/android-studio/platform/tools/adt/idea/+/mirror-goog-studio-main:transport-database/src/main/java/com/android/tools/datastore/energy/PowerProfile.java) from CPU, network, and location data. Like any maths model, it matches some devices better than others.

Comment: Thank you very much for answering. However, it seems like it is also really hard to get information regarding network and location. CPU is the only one that allows users to export the data directly.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. To clarify, the profiler's [mathematical model](https://cs.android.com/android-studio/platform/tools/adt/idea/+/mirror-goog-studio-main:transport-database/src/main/java/com/android/tools/datastore/energy/PowerProfile.java) for energy is based on CPU utilization, network type & speed and location type & duration. It's missing signal strength which is important. The user can export CPU recordings (i.e., trace files) but they cannot export CPU utilization.

As always, please consider submitting a feature request through "Help > Submit Feedback" in Android Studio.